# Index of list item clicked does not reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-mobile

On a fresh page load, the code works just fine and will display the correct information, but if you navigate backwards and try again, it displays the information from the first click. First off, here is the code and I will explain what I have...

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#months', function(){
    $('#listOfHolidays').on('click', 'li', function () {
        listIndex = $(this).index();
        $.mobile.changePage('#detail');
    });
});
$(document).on('pageinit', '#detail', function(){
    console.log(listIndex);
    $('#ho').text(holidayNames[listIndex]);
    $('#hi').text('The index of the list item clicked is: ' + listIndex);

});
```

I have 2 pages (divs with `data-role="page"`) named `#months`, which is the one containing my list of items to select from, and #detail which is a page that I want to populate based on the user's choice from the list. The id for my listview is `#listOfHolidays` and the `array` which holds the values of each item in the list is called holidayNames. I then display this basic info in the detail page in divs called #hi and #ho (some of this will be changed, I am just trying to test my way out of this problem). I have a back button enabled in the header of detail also.

Like I said, when I load this fresh, the correct holiday name and index number show up in my detail page, but when I use the back button to navigate back and try again, it populates the detail page with the same info from the first `click`.

I would assume this is because jquery is initializing the detail page in the second `$(document).on()` function with `'pageinit'` and since it is initialized with the first index and holiday name I choose, it just doesn't need to initialize again and draws the data from the first request when I click another list item.

That is my vague understanding of what is going on, so please correct me where I'm wrong and guide me in the right direction!

Thanks!

Comment: It would help to see your HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'pageinit' event only fires when the page is introduced to the DOM. Thus the code you have bound to replace the holiday text with the new one, only fires on the original click. The next few clicks do not cause that function to fire.

If you bind to the 'pagebeforeshow' then it will trigger everytime you change pages and you can bind the same function there and it should work correctly.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#detail', function () {
  console.log(listIndex);
  $('#ho').text(holidayNames[listIndex]);
  $('#hi').text('The index of the list item clicked is: ' + listIndex);
});
```

I removed some things to simplify the example.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/XEhA6/)

Comment: Perfect answer to my question! I didn't know how to put "being introduced to the DOM once" into words but that is exactly what I was thinking. Is there a blatantly obvious place to find documentation that has descriptions of terms like 'pagebeforeshow'? I looked at the definition of the .on() function and there wasn't an obvious place to look for available arguments for that first parameter

Comment: Glad I could help! The Jquery mobile documentation is currently split.  You have a demos section and an api section. The api sections lists all events and methods. Here's a link to the events you can bind to: [Jquery Mobile Events](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/)